# match on XML Tag using Regular Expression

Tags: xml, regex

I want to match this XML tag using Regex

```
"<a href="xxx">ZBL ddd</a>"
```

I want to get XXX value only when the tag value starts with ZBL

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex.

```
"<a href=([^>]*)>ZBL.*?</a>"
```

Just get `group(1)`, when this pattern is found in the string.

**Java**: -

```
String str = "<a href=\"xxx\">ZBL ddd</a>........<a href=\"abc\">ddd</a>";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<a href=([^>]*)>ZBL.*?</a>").matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output: -**

```
"xxx"
```

Comment: @MohamedKamal.. Well, I don't know `C#`. But I leave it to you to implement it for that.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP you can do the following:

```
<?php

$string = '<a href="xxx">ZBL ddd</a>';
$pattern = '/"(.*)"/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```